# how to center align two objects on the same line

Tags: html, css, alignment, display

I am trying to center align my footer menu items.  I have two items in the footer, a copyright and a menu.  How do I align both of these items in the center so they are next to each other?

What I'm trying to have the footer do

©Site Name | Disclaimer | Privacy | Advertisement | Contact Us

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/22nqe73q/

```css
.td-pb-span td-sub-footer-copy {
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
}
.td-pb-span td-sub-footer-menu {
    text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
}
.td-sub-footer-container td-container-wrap {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="td-sub-footer-container td-container-wrap ">
        <div class="td-container">
            <div class="td-pb-row">
                <div class="td-pb-span td-sub-footer-menu">
                        <div class="menu-td-demo-footer-menu-container"><ul id="menu-td-demo-footer-menu" class="td-subfooter-menu"><li id="menu-item-727" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-first td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-727"><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-728" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-728"><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-729" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-729"><a href="#">Advertisement</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-730" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-730"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul></div>                </div>

                <div class="td-pb-span td-sub-footer-copy">
                    © 2017 Site Name                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you have so many div nested, which is not needed, you might want to clean up those.

But here is the solution, div are block level element, you need to make sure set it display: inline-block or just use span.

`ul` has default 40px padding left, need overwrite that too.

set `ul li` to inline-block will make them in one row

the vertical line can be achieved by `border-right: 1px solid #000000;`, but make sure you have the following so last item does not have that line at the end.

```
ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```css
.td-pb-span td-sub-footer-copy {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.td-pb-span td-sub-footer-menu {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.td-sub-footer-container td-container-wrap {
  text-align: center;
}




.td-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.inline,
.inline * {
  display: inline;
}

.site-name {
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

.inline ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.inline ul li {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

.inline ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="td-sub-footer-container td-container-wrap ">
  <div class="td-container">
    <div class="td-pb-row">
      <span class="td-pb-span td-sub-footer-copy inline site-name">© 2017 Site Name</span>
      <div class="td-pb-span td-sub-footer-menu inline">
        <div class="menu-td-demo-footer-menu-container">
          <ul id="menu-td-demo-footer-menu" class="td-subfooter-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-727" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-first td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-727"><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-728" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-728"><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-729" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-729"><a href="#">Advertisement</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-730" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-730"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm trying to edit a pre made theme, so I would prefer not to mess with the div selectors.  Is there any way you can make it work with the code I originally had? - https://jsfiddle.net/22nqe73q/3/

Answer (score 0):

So first it looks like your selectors are a little off.

For Example:
`.td-pb-span td-sub-footer-copy`

But I think you mean:
`.td-pb-span.td-sub-footer-copy`

But to the point of the question. You need to apply `display: inline-block;` to the list item. So something like:

`.menu-item { display: inline-block; }`

Comment: I'm editing a pre made theme, so I would rather not mess with the selectors.  If I apply your suggested css the menu items align next to each other, but they are not next to the copyright.

Comment: To get the menu and copyright next to each other you'll need to apply `display: inline-block` to those elements ( .td-sub-footer-menu & .td-sub-footer-copy)

Answer (score 0):

I visit the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/22nqe73q/  .
And I edit some code.Please try for this.I edit some `CSS`.I set `CSS` according to flow(parent to child).

**EDITED jsfiddle** - https://jsfiddle.net/22nqe73q/5/

Here are the codes :

**HTML**

```
<div  class="td-sub-footer-container td-container-wrap ">
        <div  class="td-container ">
            <div class="td-pb-row">
                <div  class="td-pb-span td-sub-footer-menu">
                        <div class="menu-td-demo-footer-menu-container"><ul id="menu-td-demo-footer-menu"  class="td-subfooter-menu"><li id="menu-item-727" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-first td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-727"><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-728" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-728"><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-729" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-729"><a href="#">Advertisement</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-730" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-730"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul></div>                </div>

                <div class="td-pb-span td-sub-footer-copy">
                    © 2017 Site Name                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.td-sub-footer-copy {
  text-align:center;  
}
.td-pb-span > .menu-td-demo-footer-menu-container {
    text-align:center; 
}

.menu-td-demo-footer-menu-container >ul > li{

   list-style-type: none;
}
.td-sub-footer-container td-container-wrap {

  text-align:center;
}
```

**RESULT**

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more solution for you, with only four CSS rules:

```css
.td-pb-row {
  text-align:center;
}

.td-subfooter-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.td-sub-footer-copy,
.td-sub-footer-menu,
.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.td-sub-footer-copy::after,
.menu-item:not(:last-of-type)::after {
  content: "|";
  margin: 0 .4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="td-sub-footer-container td-container-wrap ">
  <div class="td-container">
    <div class="td-pb-row">
      <div class="td-pb-span td-sub-footer-copy">
        © 2017 Site Name
      </div>
      <div class="td-pb-span td-sub-footer-menu">
        <div class="menu-td-demo-footer-menu-container">
          <ul id="menu-td-demo-footer-menu" class="td-subfooter-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-727" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-first td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-727"><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-728" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-728"><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-729" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-729"><a href="#">Advertisement</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-730" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-730"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```